# Mongodb Native Aggregate with Cursor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I'm using mongodb native driver for nodejs. I just want to know if there are any possibilities that we can do aggregation but the method will return a cursor object? Thanks!

Comment: what are you trying to do? why would you want this?

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB's Aggregation Framework is always returning a Document (for now). So the Node driver could not return a cursor.

Answer (score 1):

From 2.6 on, mongodb aggregation returns a cursor:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6/